# Auto deploy git changes

Tags: git, web-deployment

On my server I have repository at **/var/repo/site.com.git/** and also public site folder at **/var/www/site.com/**

Working locally I'd like to push changes to the server and automatically deploy all changes to a public folder.

In a **/var/repo/site.com.git/hooks/** I created executable file *post-receive* with such content:

```
#!/bin/bash
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/site.com git checkout -f
```

Now once any change was pushed to a repository my public folder becomes updated.

But the problem is that this update becomes marked as *modified* in a public folder. And from my prospective it's expected that after such update public folder becomes up-to-date without any modifications.

Also I tried to call hard reset with pull commands without any success.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is acceptable to force reset on public before update *post-receive* script could be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
git --work-tree=/var/www/site.com --git-dir=/var/www/site.com/.git checkout -f
git --work-tree=/var/www/site.com --git-dir=/var/www/site.com/.git pull
```

In case you'd like only to pull updates you can use such script:

```
#!/bin/bash
git --work-tree=/var/www/site.com --git-dir=/var/www/site.com/.git pull
```